# What does the -> operator do?

Tags: c

I'm still fairly new to C programming so sorry for this really basic question. Can anyone tell me what this particular code does part by part? What does `->` after the stack do?

```
int StackInit(struct Stack *stack) {
    stack->currentItemIndex = -1;
    stack->initialized = true;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` is the structure dereference operator.

The left side takes a pointer to a `struct`, and the right side is a struct member.  It dereferences the pointer, then gets the named member.

So for example, `stack->initialized` is equivalent to `(*stack).initialized`.

Answer (score 0):

`struct Stack *` is a pointer to a struct named Stack. Pointer variable holds some memory address (usually of some object, the `Stack` struct in this case).
`->` operator is used to dereference (read: get the object poited to by the pointer) a pointer and to get one of the member variables at the same time (the `currentIndex` and the 'initialized' in your case).
I hope I answered your questions.